# How can I customize the value of a vuetify's v-select statement?

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js

I am trying to pass an array of objects to a v-select :items. I would like to display the object name for every option. I have roles formated like so `[{ id: '1', name: 'admin' }, { id: '2', name: 'guest' } ]`

Here is my vuetify code

```
<v-select
    :items="roles"
    v-model="value"
    label="Select Role"
 ></v-select>
```

The above code returns this view

[image]

How can I display the role name instead of [object object]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `item-name` and `item-value` props

```
<v-select
    :items="roles"
    item-text="name"
    item-value="id"
    v-model="value"
    label="Select Role"
 ></v-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use items as an array in below format

```
{
  text: string | number | object
  value: string | number | object
}
```

So, in your case `roles` should be an array-like below

```
roles: [
  {
    text: 'Role A'
    value: 'role-a'
  },
  {
    text: 'Role B'
    value: 'role-b'
  },
  {
    text: 'Role C'
    value: 'role-c'
  }
]
```

Also, If your text and value are the same then you can use shorthand format as below

```
roles: ['Role A','Role B','Role C']
```

DOCS: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/

Comment: Yeah.. I have roles formated like so [{ id: '1', name: 'admin' }, { id: '2', name: 'guest' } ]. My issue is displaying role.name as the display  and role.id and the value